# How to set the TextAppearance programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android, textview

I'm trying to set the TexAppearance of a TextView programmatically. I've look at SetTextApparence and at the TextView constructor 3rd parameter.

I can set one of Android style:

```
lvTextView.SetTextAppearance(Context, Android.Resource.Style.TextAppearanceMedium);
```

But I cannot figure how to set my own app style.
What is the syntax to reference my styles?

Answer (score 6):

Supposing your style is like this:

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    ...
</style>
```

You can set the TextView's appearance programatically as:

```
TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_title); // Your TextView
textViewTitle.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.MyStyle);
```

Comment: This is only prior to API level 23, from API level 23

textViewTitle.setTextAppearance(R.style.MyStyle);